# How many series I savings bonds can you buy at 9.62%?

Tags: united-states, government-bonds

I know the cap is $10,000 but it looks like you can put $10,000 in for each family member.  Can you also do it for an LLC or Trust fund?

Answer (score 3):

> Can you also do it for an LLC or Trust fund?

Yes. However for disregarded SMLLC or revocable trust, it will still be on your SSN.

There's some contradictory statements about how the limits are enforced on the TreasuryDirect site. See [here](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/savings-bonds/how-much-can-i-spend-own/):

> A given Social Security Number or Employer Identification Number can buy up to these amounts in savings bonds each calendar year:
>
> - $10,000 in electronic EE bonds
> - $10,000 in electronic I bonds
> - $5,000 in paper I bonds that you can buy when you file federal tax forms

However, the note below says:

> If you have an individual account and an entity account in TreasuryDirect that use the same Social Security Number, you can purchase up to the limits in each of the 2 accounts.

[This article](https://thefinancebuff.com/buy-i-bonds-business-sole-proprietor-llc.html) and [this article](https://thefinancebuff.com/buy-i-bonds-business-sole-proprietor-llc.html) seem to reinforce the notion that the enforcement is actually per account/entity and not per SSN.

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase up to $10,000 in Series I Savings Bonds at 9.62% per year. There is no limit on the number of family members that you can purchase bonds for, but each individual is limited to $10,000 in bonds. You can also purchase bonds for an LLC or Trust fund, but each entity is again limited to $10,000 in bonds.